# Как подключиться к серверу майнкрафт не запуская игру?

Tags: python, сервер, cmd, minecraft

Меня интересует техническая возможность присоединиться к серверу не запуская самой игры, у меня есть примерное представление как это должно работать, вроде мы можем посылать запрос на удалённый сервер, но как их посылать не из игры?

Я имею: Один компьютер, `windows`&l`inux` консоль, `python`, запущенный сервер `Aternos` и установленные `JDK`&`JRE`.
Цель: подключиться к серверу не запуская игры.

+`Google` не смог дать исчерпывающего ответа. Максимум что я нашёл: "Играю с ботом в майнкрафт" и всем известный `log4shell`.

Comment: Объясните, что значит "подключиться к серверу"? Подключиться, чтобы сделать что? И что значит в этом контексте "не запуская игру"?

Comment: @Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA Подключиться - значит что я могу зайти с другого аккаунта на сервер  к которому подключился через консоль и увидеть модель игрока, однако хватит просто возможности отправить запрос на майнкрафт сервер через консоль.
Не запуская игру - значит что я отправляю запрос на сервер не используя лаунчер майнкрафт или сам майнкрафт.

Comment: Протокол общения с сервером (который позволяет выполнять консольные команды) описан тут https://wiki.vg/RCON. Там же есть ссылки на библиотеки на разных языках, это если хочется свой клиент писать. Или можно использовать готовые типа https://github.com/Tiiffi/mcrcon. Что касается "увидеть модель игрока" - это вы где хотите ее увидеть? По данным игры понять координаты и как-то отобразить, т.е. реализовать то, что в приложении уже реализовано?

Comment: У вас получилось это сделать?
.

Comment: @МаратАлтмышев к сожалению у меня умерла материнка( Пока что не могу этим заниматься.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно делать бота, который будет создавать tcp подключение к твоему серверу, и отправлять соответствующие запросы. Но тут все упирается в прямые руки и непосредственно в знания.

Запрос на сервер майна просто так не отправить, так как там используется протокол шифрования сообщений, а это в свою очередь означает, что для отправки банального сообщения по типу "а залогинь ка меня" тебе нужен этот самый протокол. К тому же тебе нужно каким то образом дешифровать полученные в ответ сообщения от сервера и обрабатывать их. Для начала советую разобраться с протоколами коммуникации(общения) клиента и сервера, а уже потом на их основе сделать простенький прокси сервер, чтобы посмотреть какими данными они обмениваются

Ну а как это сделать - решай сам. Бесплатно тебе никто ничего делать не будет. Можешь поискать на github подобных ботов, возможно тебе повезет и найдешь что-то полезное

Comment: sorry, но вы имеете представления об инструментарии kali linux? Возможно там есть полезный инструмент. Если вы не в курсе то просто благодарю за этот ответ.